# Better way to type leaves of object in typescript

Tags: typescript

The goal was to add wildcards to object's paths. This object define multiple context that will be used elsewhere in code.

The constant "testB" is where the context will be used. For testing, I used booleans.

I extracted the code from my repo and managed to identify the bug. I tried to search a solution, but found nothing.

```
//if we remove the extends it work but the Leaves are no longer typed
interface Def extends LeavesType<Base>{
    a:{
        a: ContextA
    },
    b:{
        a: Base
    }
}

//true and false will be replaced in actual code
type NotWorking = {[key in Paths<Def>]: Pop<Split<key, '.'>> extends "*"?true:false}
const testB:NotWorking = {//should not have errors
    '*': true,
     "a.*": true,
    "a.a": false,
    "b.*": true,
    "b.a": false
};

interface Base{
    _: true
}

interface ContextA extends Base{
    foo: "bar"
}

//can we bump this limit up
type Paths<T, D extends number = 5> = [D] extends [never] ?
        never :
        T extends Base ?
            "" :
            T extends object ?
                {
                    [K in keyof T]-?:
                    K extends string | number ?
                        `*` | Join<K, Paths<T[K], Prev[D]>> :
                        never
                }[keyof T] :
                "";

/* ****** suspect ******* */

type LeavesType<T> = {
    [n: string]: T | LeavesType<T>
}

/* ****** helper ******* */

export type Join<K, P> =
    K extends string | number ?
        P extends string | number ?
            `${K}${"" extends P ? "" : "."}${P}` :
            never :
        never;
export type Prev = [never, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...0[]];
export type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
        S extends '' ? [] :
            S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
                [S];
export type DeepIndex<T, KS extends string[]> =
    KS[0] extends keyof T ?
        Tail<KS> extends NonEmptyArray<string> ?
            DeepIndex<T[KS[0]], Tail<KS>> :
            T[KS[0]] :
        never;
export type Tail<T> = T extends readonly any[] ?
    ((...t: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never
    : never;
export type Pop<T> = T extends [...infer R,infer H] ? H : never;
export type NonEmptyArray<T> = [T, ...T[]];
```

**Output**

```
const testB = {
    '*': true,
    "a.*": true,
    "a.a": false,
    "b.*": true,
    "b.a": false
};
export {};
```

**Compiler Options**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "target": "ES2017",
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

**Playground Link:** [Provided](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-LgVCoGLKoTQ52VTQgQwNGDwNjIZQKHCgKjiUDIGiQVjKWbOc6XHDXBx-Ey+qxQkisZDMOSkgCsYN2+xM9yr-sg+xIsEwCE7CPykT7A8gIRHQQcXesVtaw8VUUF0InU+XM4hc9QzAAVrARpBF8uT0FbaeL4F9gBpU4-VBQBz3AC0CMnS8vy9vW6h2IQJIAHxEOsG3kY9PwggADWFIMgICAClUB0Fxrz+C4rhcBwb3uNCkHQdt7lBNcPwgk8xzkdcLzSQ5jgfSAn2I0igmhaFjRjYBYUgWFuJ4yAKFYChVEPHiRK44AXTmbg+AEJxVEw1s9nyXsYj-TZHnouDIFsGTnHk6Mqk4kTuIZWBxFUeQjOM2FxJjQhlHoDgi0Q5DUPOVt8m-P051UmRNNretG3A5czlnX8akA4CArAyjIkggASXxrzSBKWNCqgQoRGFV3DQFoWS3wzjSWD3wg8j5BKsj+zkNi7IchQizOPDSV7KqED+AAGP4AEY-gAJj+ABmP4ABY-ibP4ADY-gAdj+AAOP4AE5us6-Iup6yAuv6zahs20bNvGzaps22bNoWzblsgXrOsgQE7va-Z7nuGqCHshBHPmD4sywd40r48KZArP6fOkdylxBv63iPf7-xkR7GJPKGfyof5-mh+GKsvJGvKheLfB0cBGwcfKTHygnGwAVSK9Hy1uu6vq+CmKweBGmP2N5nq0Wr3vq+YzFgZQAElyEITC-mvbHqyoEHHrByIJf2drO2RyB70fI9KIcXh2hQt4wRVpYSAAURTJQkhZXhFBcEGwSCi9+aFkWCEwm83kVp6-i1nWJaIzGLywhWlc7P3R1al63o++AvfEeTSU3HGqCQXgyCkcQTgaRR4btgAKbO7sBLAYgcABKHYwXQJCyFLlXc5wGIM7+fOEBicn5AAJVL7Zy8r0vMrbicRFa-IYjK8O6sk84Xlj3Z46lnt89byA24yReAAkh0gVeB9HrnXvHotDZN5QzYtq2HAU-ZafzrCnsNIA)

Comment: could you pls provide minimum reproducable example? I mean, is it possible to reduce the code?

Comment: If i could i would. Thats why I put most of the functions at the bottom under "helper".  This ones should be without bug since they give the right result. I will retry to reduce it.